# Is EOS.IO Archived ? No New release or security patches will be available?

Tags: eosio-code

Is the EOS.IO archived ? Please confirm. I am able to see it is archived in Github.
Any plan to coming up with an upgraded version ?

Answer (score 0):

The new version is available at Antelope.io

Comment: see here: https://github.com/antelopeIO . The core-development is taking place in the leap-repository.

Comment: New Releases can be found here: https://github.com/AntelopeIO/leap/releases

Comment: That's a fork? What happened?